# Как удалить id='position' в элемента в которого класс showing (класс showing меняется по очереди)

Tags: javascript

```js
var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
  controls[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
}

var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function previousSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function pauseSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = '&#9658;'; // play character
  playing = false;
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
}

function playSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = '&#10074;&#10074;'; // pause character
  playing = true;
  slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function() {
  if (playing) {
    pauseSlideshow();
  } else {
    playSlideshow();
  }
};

var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
  `введите сюда код`
  pauseSlideshow();
  nextSlide();
};
previous.onclick = function() {
  pauseSlideshow();
  previousSlide();
};
```

```html
<li id="position1" class="slide showing">li-1</li>
<li id="position2" class="slide">li-2</li>
<li id="position3" class="slide">li-3</li>
```

Comment: А когда нет данного класса добавлять `ID`?

Comment: Да, добавлятьь.

Comment: А классы как меняются, при клике при каких обстоятельствах...  За счет какого события? Вопрос надо формулировать так, что бы люди которые хотя и могут помочь, не спрашивали.... Не понятно ничего....

Comment: вставил код, который меняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу решает функция addRemoveId(), остальное для примера

```js
// Тут для примера реализованно  изменения по клику
const slide = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
// Все что нужно, это запускать функцию addRemoveId() для проверки наличия 
//class showing у данного узла и удлаения у данного узла ID
function addRemoveId() {

  for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    if (slide[i].classList.contains('showing')) {
      slide[i].id = ''
    } else {

      slide[i].id = 'position' + (i + 1);
    }
  }
}


for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
  slide[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
      slide[i].classList.remove('showing');
    }
    slide[i].classList.add('showing');
    addRemoveId();
  })
}
```

```css
.slide {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.showing {
  color: green;
}

#position1,
#position2,
#position3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<li id="position1" class="slide showing">Slide1</li>
<li id="position2" class="slide">Slide2</li>
<li id="position3" class="slide">Slide3</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что мне было нужно)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста..